# Listview Select and Unselect Item Android

Tags: android, listview

I am able to select items and adding to sharepreference. But once I click on selected item Its not set as unselected. When I select any tag it should add in Sharepreference and when I tap on selected item then it should be remove from sharepreferance.

Any other way of doing this will be very helpful or please show me my mistake:)

Below is my code.

```
public class Filter extends Activity {

ListView filterlist;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
String tag;
int tagcount = 0;
private ArrayList<String> taglist = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> taglist1 = new ArrayList<String>();
SharedPreferences myPrefs;
private final String TAG_NAME = "tagname";
String prefName, tagged;
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;
DatabaseHandler db;
Dbresultsummary rs;
ImageAdapter img;
ArrayList< String> preflist = new ArrayList<String>();
String item;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);
    myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    prefName = myPrefs.getString(TAG_NAME, "No Tag");

    rs = new Dbresultsummary(getApplicationContext());
    img = new ImageAdapter(this);

    filterlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.filterlist);
    filterlist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    filterlist.setAdapter(img);

    filterlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            prefName = myPrefs.getString(TAG_NAME, "No Tag");
            String s = myPrefs.getString(TAG_NAME, "No Tag");
            if (s.equals("No Tag")) {
                s = "";
            }
            else
            {

            preflist.add(s);

            }

            int len = filterlist.getCount();

            SparseBooleanArray checked = filterlist
                    .getCheckedItemPositions();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (checked.get(i)) {
                    item = taglist.get(i);
                    preflist.add(item);
            }
            }



            HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet();
            hs.addAll(preflist);
            preflist.clear();
            preflist.addAll(hs);


            s = preflist.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
                    .replace(", ", ",");



            if(s.equals(""))
            {
                s ="No Tag";
            }
            prefsEditor.putString(TAG_NAME, s);

            prefsEditor.commit();

            img.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    });

    List<Resultsummary> getall = rs.getalltag();

    for (Resultsummary cn : getall) {

        tag = cn.getTag();

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(tag, ",");
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            String temptag = (String) st.nextElement();

            taglist1.add(temptag);
            HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet();
            hs.addAll(taglist1);
            taglist1.clear();
            taglist1.addAll(hs);
        }

    }
    rs.close();
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    String listtag, seltag;
    Context mContext;
    int count = 0;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return taglist1.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lv, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.customrow);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        rs = new Dbresultsummary(getApplicationContext());

        List<Resultsummary> getall = rs.getalltag();

        for (Resultsummary cn : getall) {

            tag = cn.getTag();

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(tag, ",");
            while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
                String temptag = (String) st.nextElement();

                taglist.add(temptag);
                HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet();
                hs.addAll(taglist);
                taglist.clear();
                taglist.addAll(hs);
            }

        }
        holder.title.setText(taglist.get(position));

        prefName = myPrefs.getString(TAG_NAME, "No Tag");
        List<String> prefList = Arrays.asList(prefName.split(","));
        for (int k = 0; k < prefList.size(); k++) {
            listtag = holder.title.getText().toString();
            seltag = prefList.get(k);

            if (seltag.equals(listtag)) {
                convertView.setSelected(true);
                break;
                }
            else
            {
                convertView.setSelected(false);
            }

        }
        if (convertView.isSelected()) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(0x9934B5E4);
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
        }


        rs.close();
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filter, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // when you click setting menu
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.back:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CompleteResult.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    case R.id.cleartag:
        String defaulttag = "No Tag";
        prefsEditor.putString(TAG_NAME, defaulttag);
        prefsEditor.commit();
        img.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CompleteResult.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: Code is crazy. Pls delete unnecessary thigs and format code at next time. To solve your problem I suppose, you need create custom adapter and custom object which adapter based on. This object must contain boolean like isChecked. When you click on list item you should switch boolean value. Anyway you always can check if current value exists in preferences: if not - create it, yes - change it.

Comment: There is custom adapter as well as I have put boolean check on selecteditem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I think you need to manage it from your `ArrayAdapter` class.
There you have to remember last clicked item view and position.

Basic idea is `onListItemClick` pass the clicked position and itemview to adapter there 
we will set it's background with the color you like and changed the last selected to view
background color to default color.

```
 public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    private int mSelection = 0;

    public SampleAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Object> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    public void setSelection(int mSelection, View selectedItemView) {
        this.mSelection = mSelection;

        if (selectedItemView!= null && lastSelectedRow != null
                && selectedItemView!= lastSelectedRow) {
            lastSelectedRow
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_normal);
            selectedItemView
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_selected);
        }

        this.lastSelectedRow = selectedItemView;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //Usual code logic here....

        if (mSelection == position) {
            mViewHolder.mRootView
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_selected);
            lastSelectedRow = mViewHolder.mRootView; 
        } else {
            mViewHolder.mRootView
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_normal);
        }


        return view;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        View mRootView;
    }
}
```

On List Item click you need to pass clicked item and position to adapter.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View listItemView,
        int position, long id) {

    if(myAdapter != null )
    {
        myAdapter.setSelection(position,listItemView);
    }
}
```

if you want to call this set selection from other point 
you can call it like this.

```
myAdapter.setSelection(position,null);
mListViwe.setSelectionFromTop(position, 0);
```

Comment: whats lastSelectedRow is this