# remove previously highlighted item in listview after click on new item

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview. On this listview, I highlighted the text of a listview item. When I click on another item in the listview, I want to remove the textcolor and text style of the previous item.

here is the listview adapter code `

```
public class SubLessionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SubLessionDetail> {
Context context;
int resource, textViewResourceId;
List<SubLessionDetail> items;
List<SubLessionDetail> tempItems;
List<SubLessionDetail> suggestions;
private Dialog pinDialog;
private EditText popup_title, popup_review;
private TextView submit;
private RatingBar rating;
private String flag;
private VideoList videoList;
private CourseListMain myCourseListMain;
SubLessionAdapter.ViewHolder publicholder;
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
int listposition;

String topic_position,course_position,lession_position,item_id;

public SubLessionAdapter(Context dummyTopicList, ArrayList<SubLessionDetail> lessionLIstDetails, String flag,String course_position,String topic_position,String lession_position,String item_id) {
    super(dummyTopicList, 0, lessionLIstDetails);
    this.context = dummyTopicList;
    this.items = lessionLIstDetails;
    this.flag=flag;
    this.course_position=course_position;
    this.topic_position=topic_position;
    this.lession_position=lession_position;
    this.item_id=item_id;


    pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = pref.edit();


    myCourseListMain = PrefUtils.getMyCourse(getContext());
    listposition = pref.getInt("sublistpostion",0);

}


private class ViewHolder {

    TextView title;
    ImageView img_lock,download_green,download_gray,itemcheckded;
    LinearLayout topic;


}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SubLessionAdapter.ViewHolder holder = null;



    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_topics, parent, false);

        holder = new SubLessionAdapter.ViewHolder();
        holder.topic =(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.topic);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.img_lock = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_lock);
        holder.download_gray=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.downlaod_gray_sublist);
        holder.download_green=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.download_green_sublist);
        holder.itemcheckded =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemchecked);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else
    {
        holder = (SubLessionAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    SubLessionDetail productItems = items.get(position);
    holder.title.setText( productItems.getTitle());
    if (productItems.getLocked().equals("1")) {holder.img_lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);} else {holder.img_lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
    if (flag.equals("my_course")){holder.img_lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);}else {holder.img_lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}



    if(listposition==position){

        holder.title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4dd289"));
    }else{
        holder.title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        holder.title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }


    final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            finalHolder.title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            finalHolder.title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4dd289"));
           // finalHolder.itemcheckded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            switch (flag) {

                case "my_course":

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ContentTabActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("titlevalue",myCourseListMain.getCourseArrayList().get(Integer.parseInt(course_position)).getTopicListMain().getTopicDetailsArrayList().get(Integer.parseInt(topic_position)).getLessionArrayList().get(Integer.parseInt(lession_position)).getLessionLIstDetailArrayList().get(position).getTitle());
                    intent.putExtra("lession_id", myCourseListMain.getCourseArrayList().get(Integer.parseInt(course_position)).getTopicListMain().getTopicDetailsArrayList().get(Integer.parseInt(topic_position)).getLessionArrayList().get(Integer.parseInt(lession_position)).getLessionLIstDetailArrayList().get(position).getLession_id());
                    intent.putExtra("id", item_id);
                    intent.putExtra("lession_position", lession_position);
                    intent.putExtra("postion_current_selected_item",position+"");
                    intent.putExtra("course_position", course_position);
                    intent.putExtra("topic_position", topic_position);
                    editor.putString("sublession_has_1_item","no");
                    editor.putInt("sublistpostion",position);
                    editor.commit();
                    context.startActivity(intent);


                    break;


                case "curriculam":
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Content is Locked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

            }

        }
    });


    return convertView;

}
```

}
`

What happens now is when i click on the item, it changes textstyle and textcolor, but the previous item is still highlighted.

I want to highlight only one item at a time (clear the highlighting from the previous item).

below are some images of what's happening right now.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20677262/5576636 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a field in your data source to indicate whether the data is selected or not, and you should just change the field in your onclick listener instead of highlight the view. The specific actions of changing view should happen in `getView()` method and during this time you should set or restore text color and typeface depends on the field value.

You can do like this:

```
public class SubLessionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SubLessionDetail> {
Context context;
int resource, textViewResourceId;
List<SubLessionDetail> items;
List<SubLessionDetail> tempItems;
List<SubLessionDetail> suggestions;
private Dialog pinDialog;
private EditText popup_title, popup_review;
private TextView submit;
private RatingBar rating;
private String flag;
private VideoList videoList;
private CourseListMain myCourseListMain;
SubLessionAdapter.ViewHolder publicholder;
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private SubLessionDetail preSelectedItem;

String topic_position,course_position,lession_position,item_id;

public SubLessionAdapter(Context dummyTopicList, ArrayList<SubLessionDetail> lessionLIstDetails, String flag,String course_position,String topic_position,String lession_position,String item_id) {
    super(dummyTopicList, 0, lessionLIstDetails);
    this.context = dummyTopicList;
    this.items = lessionLIstDetails;
    this.flag=flag;
    this.course_position=course_position;
    this.topic_position=topic_position;
    this.lession_position=lession_position;
    this.item_id=item_id;


    pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = pref.edit();


    myCourseListMain = PrefUtils.getMyCourse(getContext());
    listposition = pref.getInt("sublistpostion",0);

}


private class ViewHolder {

    TextView title;
    ImageView img_lock,download_green,download_gray,itemcheckded;
    LinearLayout topic;


}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SubLessionAdapter.ViewHolder holder = null;



    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_topics, parent, false);

        holder = new SubLessionAdapter.ViewHolder();
        holder.topic =(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.topic);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.img_lock = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_lock);
        holder.download_gray=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.downlaod_gray_sublist);
        holder.download_green=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.download_green_sublist);
        holder.itemcheckded =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemchecked);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else
    {
        holder = (SubLessionAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    final SubLessionDetail productItems = items.get(position);
    holder.title.setText( productItems.getTitle());
    if (productItems.getLocked().equals("1")) {holder.img_lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);} else {holder.img_lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
    if (flag.equals("my_course")){holder.img_lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);}else {holder.img_lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}


    if (productItems.isSelected()) {
        holder.title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4dd289"));
    } else {
        holder.title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        holder.title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }


    final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (preSelectedItem != null) {
                preSelectedItem.setSelected(false);
            }
            productItems.setSelected(true);
            preSelectedItem = productItems;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            switch (flag) {

                case "my_course":

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ContentTabActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("titlevalue",myCourseListMain.getCourseArrayList().get(Integer.parseInt(course_position)).getTopicListMain().getTopicDetailsArrayList().get(Integer.parseInt(topic_position)).getLessionArrayList().get(Integer.parseInt(lession_position)).getLessionLIstDetailArrayList().get(position).getTitle());
                    intent.putExtra("lession_id", myCourseListMain.getCourseArrayList().get(Integer.parseInt(course_position)).getTopicListMain().getTopicDetailsArrayList().get(Integer.parseInt(topic_position)).getLessionArrayList().get(Integer.parseInt(lession_position)).getLessionLIstDetailArrayList().get(position).getLession_id());
                    intent.putExtra("id", item_id);
                    intent.putExtra("lession_position", lession_position);
                    intent.putExtra("postion_current_selected_item",position+"");
                    intent.putExtra("course_position", course_position);
                    intent.putExtra("topic_position", topic_position);
                    editor.putString("sublession_has_1_item","no");
                    editor.putInt("sublistpostion",position);
                    editor.commit();
                    context.startActivity(intent);


                    break;


                case "curriculam":
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Content is Locked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

            }

        }
    });


    return convertView;

}
```

You don't show your `SubLessionDetail` class, and you also should add a boolean field named `selected` in it.

Comment: will u elaborate with some code.? i have update my question with adpater class code.

Comment: @smarteducation I have shown my code changes as an example.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is save the click position of the item then check whether the clicked item's text color is cyan or not. If yes then do what you want if not then clear the list, call notify it and then add the complete list again. After notifying the addition set the text color at the position we have saved earlier.

```
 List<Bean> list;
 List<Bean> tempList;
 tempList = list;
 int pos;

 //Clean List
 public void cleanList() {
    int size = this.list.size();
    this.list.clear();
    notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
    list.addAll(tempList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now the click listener for the textView

```
 textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              pos =  = getAdapterPosition();
             if (textView.getTextColors().equals(<ColorYouDesire>)){
               Log.d(TAG,"Item Clicked Again");
               }else{
               cleanList();
               textView.setTextColor(<ColorYouDesire>);
               notifyItemChanged(pos);
               }
            }
        });
```

Try this and let me know what happened.